# Not able to load data in to MySQL DB using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am using `org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter` to write the files into DB and using `org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper` to map the columns. Data was not getting inserted in to DB and not getting any error in logs.

```
<bean id="ItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
                insert into Student_Details(Name,Id,ClassId,Rank) values (:Name, :Id, :ClassId, :Rank)
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>     
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
```

```
2016-04-28 05:45:59,904 INFO [com.sam.test.mine.scheduler.SchedulerService] [fileFirmsChannelPool-2] INFO  - <Ok file received: Student_details_20160116.OK>
Apr 28, 2016 5:45:59 AM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher run
INFO: Job: [FlowJob: [name=StudentDetailsJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{groupId=0, size=0,filename=file:/app/data/Student_details_20160116.txt, filenames=file:/app/data/Student_details_20160116.txt, now=1461836759909,type=STUDENT_DET}]
Apr 28, 2016 5:46:00 AM org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler handleStep
INFO: Executing step: [cleanStudentDetails]
2016-04-28 05:46:00,362 INFO [com.sam.test.mine.batch.JdbcUpdateTasklet] [fileFirmsChannelPool-2] INFO  - <Deleted table Student_Details successfully.>
Apr 28, 2016 5:46:00 AM org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler handleStep
INFO: Executing step: [studentDetailsStep]
Apr 28, 2016 5:46:00 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
Apr 28, 2016 5:46:00 AM org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory <init>
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
Apr 28, 2016 5:46:00 AM org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler handleStep
INFO: Executing step: [archiveStudentDetails]
2016-04-28 05:46:00,894 INFO [com.sam.test.mine.batch.FileArchiverTasklet] [fileFirmsChannelPool-2] INFO  - <Archiving ... >
2016-04-28 05:46:00,902 INFO [com.sam.test.mine.batch.FileArchiverTasklet] [fileFirmsChannelPool-2] INFO  - <success moving file to archive: /app/data/Student_details_20160116.txt to /app/archive/20160428/Student_details_20160116.txt.execution#33912>
Apr 28, 2016 5:46:00 AM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher run
INFO: Job: [FlowJob: [name=StudentDetailsJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{groupId=0, size=0, filename=file:/app/data/Student_details_20160116.txt, filenames=file:/app/data/Student_details_20160116.txt, now=1461836759909, type=STUDENT_DET}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2016-04-28 05:46:00,975 INFO [com.sam.test.mine.scheduler.SchedulerService] [fileFirmsChannelPool-2] INFO  - <finish deleting Ok file /app/data/Student_details_20160116.OK>>
```

Comment: I tested your configuration (from your XML sample) and it actually inserted  records in the database. What DMBS are you using? Can you post the `dataSource` bean (without user/password)? Do you have the correct driver in your dependencies?

Comment: Its My SQL database and i am able to insert data using "org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper" with the same writer so hope there wont be any data source or connection issue. "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" is the driver.

Comment: To make it work with MySQL DBMS, I used `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, the dependency being : `<groupId>mysql</groupId><artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>`.

Comment: Are you positive you've actually read any items? I can't see your `ItemReader` here, but that would certainly be one possible reason nothing is written. Did you check the `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` table? What was your `READ_COUNT` and `WRITE_COUNT` for the Step?

Comment: I am seeing READ_COUNT values in BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table but WRITE_COUNT as 0 and WRITE_SKIP_COUNT too same as read count.

Comment: i would suggest write your own custom writer (extends JdbcBatchItemWriter ) and override write method (call super..) and see if at all any records reach there..

Answer (score 0):

> I am seeing READ_COUNT values in BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table but WRITE_COUNT as 0 and WRITE_SKIP_COUNT too same as read count.
>
> -Amuthan

When your `READ_COUNT` matches your `WRITE_SKIP_COUNT`, it implies an exception is being thrown in your `JdbcBatchItemWriter` which has been registered as a Skippable exception in the `skippable-exception-classes` property.

```
<step id="step1">
   <tasklet>
      <chunk reader="soemReader" writer="jdbcWriter"
             commit-interval="10" skip-limit="10">
         <skippable-exception-classes>
            <include class="com.package.YourException"/>
         </skippable-exception-classes>
      </chunk>
   </tasklet>
</step>
```

I'd remove any Skippable exceptions unless you have a real business to swallow errors like this.